# Lynx options not saving

Tags: settings, lynx

In the terminal I:

- type 'lynx'
- push 'o' for options
- change setting to 'Send User-Agent header (!)'
- then 'Save options to disk' which returns the warning '(options marked (!) will not be saved)'
- then I choose 'save options to disk' and 'accept changes'

but when I quit, the options are not saved and I am not able to use the settings mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save items marked with "`(!)`", you will have to enable those in your `lynx.cfg` file (which is different from the `.lynxrc` file managed by the Options Menu.

See [`ENABLE_LYNXRC`](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/body.html#ENABLE_LYNXRC) (in the `lynx.cfg` file):

> The forms-based O'ptions menu shows a **`(!)`** marker beside items which are not saved to **`~/.lynxrc`** -- the reason for disabling some of these items is that they are likely to cause confusion if they are read from the **`.lynxrc`** file for each session. However, they can be enabled or disabled using the **`ENABLE_LYNXRC`** settings. The default (compiled-in) settings are shown below. The second column is the name by which a setting is saved to **`.lynxrc`** (which is chosen where possible to correspond with **`lynx.cf`**g). Use ***"OFF"*** to disable writing a setting, ***"ON"*** to enable it. Settings are read from .lynxrc after the corresponding data from **`lynx.cfg`**, so they override **`lynx.cfg`**, which is probably what users expect.